# I can go back below API 21 devices in android

Tags: android, manifest

I am using material design, in material design I can go back DeveloperNetwork.java to MainActivity.java. At below API 21 devices, I can't go back in KitKat, JellyBean, etc. What happened?. I can't search how to solve this problem? Here is `DeveloperNetwork.java`

```
public class DeveloperNetwork extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_developer_network);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

manifests.java

```
<activity
    android:name=".Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.javaclass.MainActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".DeveloperNetwork"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_developer_network"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.javaclass.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Lollipop Back Button doesn't work in Previous Version

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `android:parentActivityName` attribute to your .DeveloperNetwork activity tag like below.

```
  <activity
      android:name=".DeveloperNetwork"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_developer_network"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:parentActivityName="com.example.javaclass.MainActivity"
      >
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value="com.example.javaclass.MainActivity" />
  </activity>
```